# Как запретить изменять zoom на своем сайте?

Tags: jquery, браузер, zoom

Бывает, зажимают <kbd>ctrl</kbd> и крутят колесико мыши, благодаря чему меняется zoom браузера.
Как это ограничить?

Comment: Никак.... Это функция браузера...

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/52258

Comment: @Air Поле для ответа находится чуть ниже.

Comment: @AK, четыре слова оформлять ответом? Я считаю, что это больше похоже на комментарий...

Comment: @Air Дописать до полноценного ответа конечно придётся, куда ж без этого.